# Android : Use ListActivity with BaseActivity

Tags: android

I am working on my project and I have created a class which uses ListActivity to display the listview contents. But I want BaseActivity as well so that i can show the drawer toggle and all. When I copy the drawertoggle methods it shows an error saying that please extend class with BaseActivity.Below is the piece of code:

LibraryShowData

```
public class LibraryShowData extends ListActivity     {
    private LibraryDatabase libhelper;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LibraryDatabase empClick = new LibraryDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        Cursor cursor = empClick.getDetails();
        ListView listView = getListView();

        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.library_header_layout, null);

        if (cursor != null)

            listView.addHeaderView(header);
        listView.setAdapter(
                new android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.library_disp_layout, cursor, new String[]{
                        "_id", "Author", "Book","ISBN"
                }, new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.auth, R.id.book,R.id.isbn}, 0));






    }

    @Override                                 // it gives error as BaseActivity should be extended
    protected boolean useDrawerToggle() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_gallery)
            return true;

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
            onBackPressed();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: `useDrawerToggle` is not an overridable method of `ListActivity`

Comment: There is not any `useDrawerToggle` methods to override in `ListActivity`, What are you trying to do actually ?

Comment: there is separate class BaseActivity which has userDrawerToggle method

Comment: Yeah, and you aren't using BaseActivity

Comment: i'm but i haven't mentioned here, the problem is with this class. See i want to extend my LibraryShowData class with BaseActivity class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you are using the `ListActivity` for in the code is the `getListView()` method. You can do the same with `BaseActivity` by using `setContentView(android.R.layout.list_content)` and `findViewById(android.R.id.list)`

```
public class LibraryShowData extends BaseActivity {
    private LibraryDatabase libhelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(android.R.layout.list_content); // the layout used by ListActivity
        ListView listView = findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        LibraryDatabase empClick = new LibraryDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        Cursor cursor = empClick.getDetails();

        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.library_header_layout, null);
```